# google search resultStat

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-search-console

when you do a google on "site:yoursite.com" it will display the items/pages that are under that site. on the top of the search result, there is an item that says "About 999 results (0.49 seconds)". How do I get that piece of information from either Google Analytics or Webmaster tools. Im using PHP as my lang.

I have over a hundred sites that I wanted to track. And using the old ([http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=site:yoursite.com](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=site%3ayoursite.com)) doesn't work because google imposed a query limit. So im thinking that maybe I can get these info from GA and/or WMT.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see amount of indexed pages in **Webmaster Tools** under **Google Index** -> **Index Status**.

However, I think the exact number might be slightly different from *site:yoursite.com*.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Splinterteal! The info i needed what infact on that page. The question now is how do i get that automatically from a PHP script. Thanks again!